# Run a function on all filenames in a list

Tags: bash

I use `ag` to select filenames and pipe them into `fzy` with the following script

```
set "$(ag -g "\.gz$" archives/ | fzy )"
echo "selected file: $1"
```

How can I run a function on all files in the folder `archives` , so **only files in are selected, that are newer than already existing files with the same name the folder `itp-files/`?** and pipe only those into `fzy` then?

I tried something like

```
for f in $(ag --nonumbers -g "\.gz$" archives/); do
  echo do something with $f and only output if file is older than the same in itp-files/;
done | fzy
```

But I am not sure how to compare the filetimes ike this

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get all the files that end in .gz. You can just use the built-in `find` command to do that: `find tmp/ archives/ -type f -name '*.gz'`

Comment: Sure, but I need the selection possibility and the fuzzy search functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried something like
>
> ```
> for f in $(ag --nonumbers -g "\.gz$" archives/); do
>  echo do something with $f and only output if file is older than the same in tmp/;
> done | fzy
> ```
>
> But I am not sure how to compare the filetimes ike this

If you like your construction `for ... in ...` with `ag`, you may compare timestamps like this:

```
for f in $(ag --nonumbers -g "\.gz$" archives/); do
  fn=$(basename $f)
  if [ $f -ot tmp/$fn ]; then
    fzy $f
  fi
done
```

Ajust full path of `tmp` folder, if needed.
`-ot` means "older than".

**Narrowed solution** (to provide a list of newline-separated items for `fzy`):

```
find archives -iname "*.gz" -type f -printf "%f\n" | \
xargs -I '{}' find itp-files -name '{}' -type f -newer '{}' -printf "%f\n" | \
sort | \
fzy
```

Comment: `fzy`doesn't work like you suggested, but I got it thanks to your `-ot` and the basename trick ... this is my solution: `find archives/ -name "*.gz" |while read f; do fn=$(basename $f); if [ $f -ot itp-files/$fn ]; then echo $f;   fi; done | fzy` ... if you add it to your answer, I can accept it as the solution

Comment: Good to know about `fzy`. Never used it before. I've added another solution. Piping `find`s is working too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xargs` command to run a command on each line of output.

For example: `find . -name '*.bak' -type f -print | xargs rm -r` will remove all files that end in .bak

Comment: How do I use find to compare the dates then?

Comment: This is just another aproach like the already existing with just ag. I added an approach, that shows my struggle

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `find -exec` approach, something like:

```
find /directory -name "*.gz" -mtime +5 -exec ag -g {} \; | fzy
```

This means:

- Search within the `/directory`
- The name of the file needs to end with `.gz` (file extension)
- The last modification date needs to be older than 5 days (can be altered according to your wishes)
- `-exec ag -g {}` : executed the `ag` command, using the `-g` switch, on the find result (`{}`).
- `\;` ends the `-exec` part.
- You can launch the `fzy` command on the results.

Feel free to add comments in case you have doubts.

Comment: This is just another aproach like the already existing with just `ag`. I added an approach, that shows my struggle

Comment: I've found this command for checking the last modification date of a file: `date -r filename +%s`, does this help?